# Directly loading your object from a Linq select?

Tags: c#, linq

If I have an object that matches the select at the bottom of this statement.  Is there a way to automatically load the object?

```
            var qaResults = from q in allQuestions
                            join la in allLeaderAnswers on q.QuestionID equals la.QuestionID into leaderAnswers
                            from la in leaderAnswers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join ta in allTeacherAnswers on q.QuestionID equals ta.QuestionID into teacherAnswers
                            from ta in teacherAnswers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new
                            {
                                QuestionID = q.QuestionID,
                                ID = q.ID,
                                QuestionText = q.Description,
                                LeaderAnswerText = la.Comment,
                                LeaderAnswerRating = (la.AnswerOptionKey == null ? 0 : la.AnswerOptionKey),
                                TeacherAnswerText = ta.Comment,
                                TeacherAnswerRating = (ta.AnswerOptionKey == null ? 0 : ta.AnswerOptionKey)
                            };
```

**My Object properties:**

```
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string LeaderAnswerText { get; set; }
    public int LeaderRating { get; set; }
    public string TeacherAnswerText { get; set; }
    public int TeacherRating { get; set; }
```

**What I've tried:**

```
            List<EvaluationResultSet> ResultSet = new List<EvaluationResultSet>();
            ResultSet = qaResults.ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean with "load it"?

Comment: Oh, it's not called "loading". It's called "creating an object of a specific type".

Comment: @OndrejJanacek ok...  thank you.  That was my next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify that object's class name in your `select`

```
select new EvaluationResultSet //Here 
    {
        QuestionID = q.QuestionID,
        ID = q.ID,
        QuestionText = q.Description,
        LeaderAnswerText = la.Comment,
        LeaderAnswerRating = (la.AnswerOptionKey == null ? 0 : la.AnswerOptionKey),
        TeacherAnswerText = ta.Comment,
        TeacherAnswerRating = (ta.AnswerOptionKey == null ? 0 : ta.AnswerOptionKey)
    };
```

Currently you are not specifying any class name hence it is creating an [Anonymous Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

If you are using Entity framework or LINQ to SQL, then just make sure that the class you are using is not the one generated through Entity framework / LINQ to SQL, because you can't project to generated classes, in that case you have to define a new class.

Comment: I think the model name should be not EvaluationResultSet, just EvaluationResult.

Comment: @Alexander Check the question. There is a a list of `EvaluationResultSet`.

Comment: And? Model is a single object, the query returns a list of objects, but not object which is list.